# Issues with JDBC navigation with resultSet.next();

Tags: java

My code belows doesnt work, just keep pointing the cursor at the first record, and when i try to replace the if statement with a while  or for loop it just loops to the last record on my data table, when i click the button that performs the Action

```
Try {
    string host="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
    string uName="admin1";
    string uPass="admin"
    string SQL="SELECT * FROM Workers";

    Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
    Statement stmt=Con.createStatement();
    ResultSet=stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
    if (rs.next()) 
    {    
        string fname=rs.getString(first_name);
        string lname=rs.getString(last_name):    
        txtFname.setText(fname);    
        txtLname.setText(lname);
    }
    else{
        rs.previous(); 
       //throw some sql error here}
    }
    catch(SQLException err) {
         system.out.println(err.getMessage);
    }
```

how do i get around this and get to a second, third,fourth to nth record **successively** (not simultaneously).

Comment: remove `rs.previous()` from else. Remove else itself you do not need it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(SQL);` instead of `ResultSet=stmt.executeQuery(SQL);` and `String` instead of `string` and `try` instead of `Try` and `System` instead of `system` and a semicolon after `string uPass="admin"`??

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `ResultSet.next()` [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()), calling `rs.next()` once as an `if` condition will only move the cursor one position forward from its starting position. Hence, you only see the first record.

Replacing your `if` statement with either a `while` or `for` loop will cause the cursor to iterate through your entire result set. However, each iteration of the your current loop keeps overwriting the value of `txtFname` and `txtLname` with that of the "current" record. In order to capture the value of the 2nd, 3rd, 4th records etc... you will need to create a new TextComponent object at each iteration. For example,

```
// use some lists to capture intermediate records (for illustration only)
List<JTextComponent> allFnames = new ArrayList<JTextComponent>();
List<JTextComponent> allLnames = new ArrayList<JTextComponent>();
while(rs.next()) {
    string fname=rs.getString(first_name);
    string lname=rs.getString(last_name):

    JTextComponent txtFname = new JTextComponent(); // new object
    txtFname.setText(fname);
    allFnames.add(txtFname);

    JTextComponent txtLname = new JTextComponent(); // new object
    txtLname.setText(lname);
    allLnames.add(txtFname);
}
```

Now at the end of the `while` loop, the two lists will contain all your records.

Answer (score 0):

[javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#previous()) says -

```
ResultSet#previous() -Moves the cursor to the previous row in this ResultSet 
object.When a call to the previous method returns false, the cursor is positioned
before the first row. Any invocation of a ResultSet method which requires a 
current row will result in a SQLException being thrown.
```

*So in certain point of time your `if(rs.next())` returns false then the else part executes and the cursor moves to the previous row in this ResultSet. Then When a call to the previous method returns false, the cursor is positioned before the first row. and then it will throw Exception*

do it this way

```
if (!resultSet.next() ) {
    System.out.println("resultset does not data");
} else {

    do {
     string fname=rs.getString(first_name);
     string lname=rs.getString(last_name):    
     txtFname.setText(fname);    
     txtLname.setText(lname);
    } while (resultSet.next());
}
```

One more thing check the comment of Nivedita and sort out the errors